# ¿Cómo corregir $ is not a function en wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Tengo un script que no he programado ademas de estar ofuscado, ya lo he incluido a wordpress pero me da este error:

> $ is not a function.

He agregado este script en mi archivo function.php así:

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
  wp_register_script('build', get_template_directory_uri() .       '/js/build.js',array('jquery'), 1.1, true);
  wp_enqueue_script('build');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

He investigado que el problema se corrige con estas líneas al iniciar Jquery, pero el código esta ofuscado.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
Query(document).ready(function($) {
}
```

Comment: Ya intentaste con este post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24719/jquery-conflict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var j = jQuery.noConflict();` es utilizado cuando tienes dos o más versiones de jQuery al mismo tiempo y pueden entrar en conflicto. Lee más aquí

*Wordpress* ya carga de manera nativa javascript y utiliza `jQuery.noConflict()`, por lo que *$ no funciona* pero sí *jQuery*.

Sólo está mal escrito tu código, debería ser:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  /* Mas código aquí */
});
```

Comment: Gracias, el problema es que el script que tengo no lo hice yo y esta ofuscado y minificado

Comment: @baxi2990 te refieres al archivo */build.js*? Por qué no lo modificas si éste tiene el error? Puedes darle formato legible al archivo con [esta herramienta](http://jsbeautifier.org/) y luego minificarlo nuevamente.

Comment: lo he desofuscado pero aun presenta problemas, pero ya es algo específicamente del script.